# Better use of models and migration in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

Hey.
I'm having a hard time migrating changes I've done i my config/doctrine/schema.yml file.

I added the column  `age`  to the  `user`  table. Then I did a  `php symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff`  followed by  `php symfony doctrine:migrate` .

Looking in my database, the column  `age`  is now added, without deleting any data.

But, my /lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseUser.class.php is not changed, there is no  `age`  field or functions for  `age` . So I also did the command  `php symfony doctrine:build-model` . Finally the model is updated/migrated too.

So I wonder, is this the only way? Seems like a lot of work, and I'm afraid to miss something each time doing it.

Could I go right into phpmyadmin, add changes in the database there and just do a  `php symfony doctrine:build-schema` , and like that skip the migration part (two commands).

Also when the comes to use of models, am I right that /lib/model/doctrine/User.class.php is where I can make functions and such for my User "data class"? Like, making a function  `isFemale` . If not, where would that kind of function be?

This might be a bad question, but why is the model layer inside the /lib/doctrine path? As far as I have learned, you keep modules inside apps, where you create your view and controller. Why should the model be outside. Like this I can make models without attached controller and view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why should the model be outside

Because models can be used everywhere in your project, in example, in different applications and modules.

> Could I go right into phpmyadmin, add changes in the database there and just do a php symfony doctrine:build-schema , and like that skip the migration part (two commands).

Of course you can, but migrations are a good approach to track your schema when deploying to production or working in team.

Here how I use doctrine migrations (simple use-case):

1. Add a column `age` to my `User` model in `schema.yml`
2. `./symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff`. Migration class(-es) have been generated.
3. `./symfony doctrine:migrate`. Column `age` successfully added to table.
4. `./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`. Build forms/filters/models

That's it. The main idea is that `doctrine:generate-migrations-diff` class:

1. Gathers information about all your models' structure (php-representation of schema.yml)
2. Compares your `schema.yml` and info from (1)
3. Generates migration classes based on difference

> Also when the comes to use of models, am I right that /lib/model/doctrine/User.class.php is where I can make functions and such for my User "data class"? Like, making a function isFemale . If not, where would that kind of function be?

Yes, you can add such method to `User` model because it's about users.

Comment: Now I just got an error, could not generate migration classes from difference. No other error than that :(

Comment: Johannes, it means that schema and models are synced. Remember not to build models until you create migrations.